# How To get multiple array and change value of its related array key using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery

This is the sample image of the output. What I want is if I change the quantity in that column its co-related total-price will change also. I want to achieve this injquery yet Im struggling.This is my current code and it still has error if i update the quantity all the total price will change which is wrong I want to only change the total price of the edited column.

```
var delay = (function(){
    var timer = 0;
    return function(callback, ms){
      clearTimeout (timer);
      timer = setTimeout(callback, ms);
    };
  })();

  $(".qty-mod").keyup(function(){
          var qty = $(this).val();
          delay(function(){
          var newprice = qty * totalorgprice
          $(".price-total").val(newprice);
          console.log(qty);
      }, 1000);
  });
```

[image]

Comment: Where is `totalorgprice` defined ? Can you include `html` at Question and create a stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: Which column? Please [edit] your question to help readers to understand what you're talking about

Comment: Ive updated the image you can view it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've bound all `.qty-mod` at once, and this is good.

But when in the `keyup()` function you're operating on only one `.qty-mod`, so should update only the corresponding `.price-total`.
And currently you're explicitly updating *all of them*!

```
  $(".qty-mod").keyup(function(){
      var qty = $(this).val();
      var newprice = qty * totalorgprice;
      $(<< here should refer to the involved .price-total only >>).val(newprice);
      console.log(qty);
  });
```

Since you didn't show your HTML code I can only guess that your data is displayed in a `<table>`. If so, the `<< here ... only >>` above might be something like:

```
'.price-total', $(this).closest('tr')
```

Explained for the case you're not easy with jQuery:

```
  '.price-total',    // an element with class "price-total"
  $(this)            // in the context of 
    .closest('tr')   // the <tr> parent of the [$(this)] current element
```

Comment: @EdylI.Templado Sorry, I mixed complete code with the fragment I showed. Now corrected: look at my edit.

Comment: I change my code to               var totalprice = $('.price-total').find($(this).closest('tr')).val();
 and still didnt work.

Comment: @EdylI.Templado No, double check my answer: the whole statement is `$('.price-total', $(this).closest('tr')).val(newprice);`.

Comment: I updated my code with       var price = $('.price-total', $(this).closest('tr')).val(100);
        console.log(price); and still get undifine error on console I added 100 just for testing

Comment: @EdylI.Templado According to your HTML code, I don't change my suggested statement. What is exactly the complete error message? BTW, looking at your HTML I guess you have to do the same to get the involved `.price-mod` rather than `totalorgprice`.

Comment: yeah I think so I also need to get the price-mod yet if I get the way getting the value of .price-total I can also get the price-mod by that way

Comment: @EdylI.Templado Don't mind: I just realized you execute your price computation with `delay()`, so `this` is not known inside it. I don't see the advantage of this delay, so you might simply work directly, with the statement I proposed. Otherwise it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: this was the error  [prevObject: n.fn.init[0], context: undefined, selector: ".price-total"]